With multiple access points for a single SSID is it better to have one common channel or different channels for 802.11g+n 2.4GHz?
I have 4 Wifi access points of the same SSID but from different manufacturers. It's about 2.4 GHz 802.11g+n and other SSIDs are also present. As the access points are in the same house but on different floors, the radio signals overlap. There are also neighbouring Wifi radio signals.
Is it better (i.e. more stable connections) to have a single common channel or to let each access point have its own channel?

You want to interleave 2.4 GHz channels 1, 6 and 11 between accesspoints, as even the beacons cost airtime. Overlap means the accesspoints have to share airtime, in a busy WiFi environment this impacts throughput.
At 5 GHz walls have a high attenuation and this problem is less severe, but still relevant. However available channels per region and DFS make it more complicated.
The roaming is up to the client devices, you will have a suboptimal experience because your accesspoints don't do 802.11r.
To improve the likeliness clients hop to a new accesspoint you could reduce the transmit power of the accesspoints to limit range. There will always remain some sticky clients.
Neighbouring WiFi can be a problem if they do not adhere to the 1,6,11 channels, but it's mostly out of your control. Managed accesspoints can do a scan and each pick their best option within with respect to the neighbours and not overlapping each other.

I would recommend getting four centrally managed accesspoints that automatically pick channels and assist with roaming. It will be a much better experience.

I saw that the channels 1, 6, and 11 are the suggested ones for the US. For Australia and other (?) countries I saw that 1, 5, 9, and 13 are suggested. Any hint for Germany?

@monok 1,6,11 is worldwide.  (1,5,9 overlap, that's bad)

see https://support.metageek.com/hc/en-us/articles/201034400-Choosing-a-WiFi-Channel for "If you are using 2.4 GHz in the United States, try to stick with channel 1, 6 or 11 to reduce the potential for future overlap. For some other countries such as Australia, use channels 1, 5, 9, and 13. "

Definitely you need different channels.
You want device to connect to specific APs.
If you set same SSID and same password, the devices will shift between APs seamlessly. But you want different channels so you have best possible links between devices and APs that the same devices are connected to at given time.
If possible, choose channels far apart. Assuming there are no other APs. You can scan first with obe of many tools.

I am wondering why the Fritzbox has the option to share the settings (including channel number) to the APs in the mesh. Using that option, which I currently don't, would result in the same channel numbers for 2 out of  my 4 APs (other APs are TPlink).

It's different topology if you use in a mesh or if you use them as independent APs. I suppose if you use them in the nesh they need to be on the same channel since link between them also go over radio channel. If you use them as a independent APs in a single network, then i propose to use different channels (in this case you need to connect them to the same network with some other way, eg eth cable). The reason is that then they do not interfere with each other.. the one APs link with a device is noise for the other AP.

It probably makes very little difference given that WiFi throughput is much higher than it used to be. With the higher channel coding rates available, even on pokey 2.4GHz, there's usually more than enough bandwidth to handle multiple devices at once.
As a first pass you have several steps you can take:

Let the APs figure it out.

Many APs (especially ones that support mesh) will sample the spectrum and choose channels to avoid strong nearby interferers.

Divide your use cases.

Put heavy, latency-sensitive traffic (like your smart TV) on 5G, and dedicate an AP for it (basically, make the device only use the 'good' AP on 5G.) Use 2.4G or auto-discover for everything else.
Why continue with 2.4G? Although there isn't as much spectrum on it compared to 5G, 2.4G is still valuable as it propagates better in most situations.
Want more control?

Look for interferers and move your APs to different channels.

This is what you're asking about. So, sure, you can select different channels for your common-SSID APs, but which channels? You need more information.
There’s a good tool set from Metageek called inSSIDer that shows what APs are on the air, their relative signal strengths, and what bandwidth modes they're using (20, 40, 80 or 160MHz.) You can find yourself some unused spectrum to set up a wide-bandwidth link.
Even if you don't set up the AP channels yourself, inSSIDer is still useful to see what your APs decided to do on their own.
